# numpy indexed list error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to create an indexed np.ndarray as:

```
dos2[q] = np.empty((dos[q].shape[0], dos[q].shape[1] + 1), dtype=dos[q].dtype)
```

with q properly defined.
I am getting error:

```
NameError: name 'dos2' is not defined
```

The shape and type of dos[q] is:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(301, 18)
```

If I create it out of q loop as:

```
dos2 = np.empty((dos.shape[0], dos.shape[1] + 1), dtype=dos.dtype)
```

then everything is fine. (dos is also out of the `q` loop in this case, with same type and dimension)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is simply just the declaration of dos2. If you want to define `dos2[q]`, `dos2`should have been defined before

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `doc2` is not defined when you try to assign

```
dos2[q] = np.empty((dos[q].shape[0], dos[q].shape[1] + 1), dtype=dos[q].dtype)
```

Everytime you want when you try to assign something in part of the array you need to define it before.